# How to trace ObjectContext for EF6?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6

I need to trace SQL statements of `ObjectContext` Class of `EntityFramework 6`.
Can I do it with `EntityFramework` opportunities without any outside extensions?
Sample code will be excellent! :)

```
using (var db = new SomeContext()) 
{ 
    db.Log += Debug.WriteLine;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2014/02/09/ef-6-1-turning-on-logging-without-recompiling/